# Script error for ext:form FormEditor Viewmodel

Tags: typo3, yaml

Trying to implement an custom form element for ext:form i registred a ViewModel for the Backend in yaml:

```
              formEditor:
                dynamicRequireJsModules:
                  additionalViewModelModules:
                    - 'TYPO3/CMS/MyExt/Backend/FormEditor/CheckboxtextareaViewmodel'
```

When i open the form in the backend the console show this error:

```
Error: Script error for "TYPO3/CMS/MyExt/Backend/FormEditor/CheckboxtextareaViewmodel"
```

it tries to resolve this file:

```
https://....de/typo3/TYPO3/CMS/MyExt/Backend/FormEditor/CheckboxtextareaViewmodel.js
```

i used this example: http://labor.99grad.de/typo3-tx_form-eigenes-formularelement-erstellen-custom-form-element/

how can i fix it?

Comment: Is `CheckboxtextareaViewmodel.js` available in your extension? Did you adjust the provided example to your needs?

Comment: Yes, ist present here: 
/typo3conf/ext/MyExt/Resources/Public/Javascript/Backend/FormEditor/CheckboxtextareaViewModel.js
and Yes i did

Comment: solved it: Javascript -> JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

solved it: Javascript -> JavaScript